# Python and Scrapy - Scraper does not return results

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Hello and thanks in advance for any assistance with this issue I'm having.  I have never posted for coding help before and I'm very new to programming.  Self taught old guy who is trying to learn something new and maybe build something to save the world (Or just build something. :))

I have scrapy fired up and when I run my terminal command "scrapy crawl coops" I always get the DEBUG: Crawled (200) and don't see any "Found details:" entrys.  I'm able to run scrapy shell "http://coopdirectory.org/directory.htm" and get results manually with the shell.  When I try to yield to a .jl or .js file they are empty as well.  (I have made this work great with the scrapy tutorial quotes).  Below is my code and below that are the results. Any direction on this would be great.

```py
import scrapy


class CoopsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "coops"
    start_urls = [
    'http://coopdirectory.org/directory.htm',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for coop in response.css('div.coop'):
            yield {
                'name': coop.css('h3 a::text').getall(),
                'address': coop.css('.address::text').getall(),
                'website': coop.css('.web-address::text').getall(),
                'phone': coop.css('.phone::text').getall(),
                'org_type': coop.css('.org-type::text').getall(),
                'inactive': coop.css('.inactive-alert::text').getall(),
                'notes': coop.css('.note::text').getall(),
            }
```

---

RESULTS

```
PS C:\Users\scott\Documents\WebScrapeProjects\coops\coops> scrapy crawl coops
2020-04-28 19:08:31 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.1.0 started (bot: coops)
2020-04-28 19:08:31 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019), cryptography 2.8, Platform Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
2020-04-28 19:08:31 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2020-04-28 19:08:31 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'coops',
 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 7,
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'coops.spiders',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['coops.spiders'],
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) '
               'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 '
               'Safari/537.36'}
2020-04-28 19:08:31 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 3f2a17b73c1f55b3
2020-04-28 19:08:31 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-04-28 19:08:32 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-04-28 19:08:32 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-04-28 19:08:32 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-04-28 19:08:32 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-04-28 19:08:32 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-04-28 19:08:32 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-04-28 19:08:32 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://coopdirectory.org/directory.htm> (referer: None)
2020-04-28 19:08:32 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-04-28 19:08:32 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 316,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 303338,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.808906,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 29, 0, 8, 32, 936826),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 29, 0, 8, 32, 127920)}
2020-04-28 19:08:32 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css-selector (`'div.coop'`) is not selecting anything and so nothing can be yielded inside your loop. You can test this by opening a scrapy shell (`scrapy shell "http://coopdirectory.org/directory.htm"`) and then type `response.css('div.coop')`. You will see that an empty selection (`[]`) will be returned.

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve exactly, but here is an example that extracts all of the information that you are trying to extract and just returns it:

```py
import scrapy


class CoopsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "coops"
    start_urls = ['http://coopdirectory.org/directory.htm']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'name': response.css('h3 a::text').getall(),
            'address': response.css('.address::text').getall(),
            'website': response.css('.web-address a::text').getall(),
            'phone': response.css('.phone::text').getall(),
            'org_type': response.css('.org-type::text').getall(),
            'inactive': response.css('.inactive-alert::text').getall(),
            'notes': response.css('.note::text').getall(),
        }
```

Just a hint: You might have a hard time scraping this website because the individual co-ops are not inside individual < div >-containers. This makes it somewhat difficult to seperate the individual information. Maybe you can find another website that also contains the information you need and is better suited for scraping or skip scraping and use open data-sets right away.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  Yes I'm trying to gather the information for each coop in the web page.  Since I'm very new to programming and scrapy I googled scrapy and data sets and found a tutorial that I will give a try.  So for someone who is just starting like myself they might find this useful as well.    Regarding the first question on what I was trying to do?  Well my end goal is to have this all imported into a database and the "for" line was creating the dictionary though I'm not sure I needed that at this point.  Thanks again for the direction.